# Titan BatchLoading berkeleydb not persistent

Tags: persistent, berkeley-db, titan, bulk-load

i really cant figure out where my problem is.
Im using Titan 0.5.0 (It's the same problem with the newer Titan versions...)

I want to load a bunch of vertices and edges from a csv file with 100k entries (each line results in at least 3 nodes and some edges) into my graph. 
It's taking about 5 minutes to finally complete the import.

So i tried the same with the configuration `storage.batch-loading = true.` 
Well it's significant faster with only 2 minutes to complete the import.

But the problem is, if im turning on the `storage.batch-loading = true` option, the nodes and edges are not saved persistent to the database. So if im shutting down Gremlin and reopening my graph, it's empty.

It's working like a charm with the `storage.batch-loading` set to false. It takes longer but the entries are saved persistent.

Yes, i'm commiting the Batchgraph after the import and also the graph itself.
Am I'm missing something?

In this example i want to import just about 30k nodes for testing, but they are also not saved persistent.
Configuration:

```
storage.backend=berkeleyje
storage.directory=graph

storage.batch-loading = true

query.fast-property =  true
```

Gremlin Script:

```
g = TitanFactory.open("../graphs/batchImportTest2/batchImportTest2.properties")

//1 Prepare Graph for import

m = g.getManagementSystem();
username = m.makePropertyKey('username').dataType(String.class).make()
m.buildIndex('byUsername',Vertex.class).addKey(username).unique().buildCompositeIndex()
email = m.makePropertyKey('email').dataType(String.class).make()
m.buildIndex('byEmail',Vertex.class).addKey(email).unique().buildCompositeIndex()
m.commit()
g.commit()

//2 Import Nodes and Edges

bg = new BatchGraph(g, VertexIDType.STRING, 50000)
new File("userInfo_js.txt").eachLine({ final String line ->def (username,email) = line.split('\t')*.trim();def userVertex = bg.getVertex(username) ?: bg.addVertex(username); userVertex.setProperty("username", username);userVertex.setProperty("email", email)})
bg.commit()
g.commit()
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried to reproduce it, but it all works as expected. See my Gist for a complete record of my shell session, maybe you can spot a difference:

https://gist.github.com/dkuppitz/5319a2fa7f9a8069fa15

Comment: Hello Daniel,
thanks for you time and answer. Well, if im doing it the exact same way like you (the user.txt with 11 user...) it surprisingly works for me as well. the only two differences i could spot is that youre using linux and im using windows. and that you had a "g.shutdown()" at the end.

BUT. the small user file with only email and username was just for testing the batchimport.
I do have a big file with 100k entries, and a lot more nodes, attributes and edges which are creating while batchImporting.
And there it still doesnt work, also not with "g.shutdown()" in the end.
...

Comment: ... But i can spot, that with the small userfile and "g.shutdown()" in the end, the graph is closing with "exit".

If im trying the same procedure with my big file, the graph is not closing with "exit". It stays in a state, where you cant type anything, the gremlin line is gone in the beginning, but its not closing the window. Is this supposed to be like that? Or has this something to do with my problem?
Thanks so much for your help!

Comment: `g.shutdown()` was done automatically in older versions, then it was removed and I guess it's back in newer versions (0.9+). So, yea, what you see is kinda expected, since the shell is waiting for some background threads that are never terminated without an explicit `g.shutdown()`, which in turn leads to some weird effects when you force the shell to close using CTRL+C.

Comment: Ah alright. But even though ive added the g.shutdown to my Code it doesnt save the Data persitent with my big import :/    as i said, it works now with the small User import. But with the Same settimgs and commands it wont Work with the big File...

Comment: Maybe memory issues, maybe a parser error? My next step would be to truncate the huge file and try again. Like `head -n10000 hugefile.txt > truncated.txt`.

Comment: But how could this be a parser error if everything is imported correctly? After importing i can query the graph and everything is available. 
Buter after closing and reopening it everythings gone...

Comment: Hm, good point. Can you create a Gist of your shell session like I did before? Maybe I can spot the issue.